# Code quality tool for JIRA

Tags: javascript, python, code-analysis, continuous-integration

We use JIRA from Atlassian and would like to know if there are analysis tools for measuring code quality when the code is written in javascript, python and perl?

I have signed up for measuring code coverage via github where I also can connect to travis-ci, but I would like to know if there is something that can report directly in JIRA. It is ok if it is not free of charge, we have a budget. The requirements are also loosely defined, we would like to know something similar to what pycharm reports directly about "codesmell" and similar possible issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code static analysis you can use SonarQube:

- it supports coverage and complexity metrics
- it takes external tools results (pylint, jslint, etc)
- supports Js and Python, not sure about Perl
- provides dashboards and timelines

There is a JIRA plugin (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JIRA+Plugin), but it seems to be deprecated.

Also in the marketplace, there is a JIRA connector for Sonar (https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/es.excentia.jira.plugins.jira-sonarqube-connector-plugin/server/overview).